# NullPointer trying to Export Google Doc

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Using the Google Drive SDK (v2-rev57-1.13.2-beta) from Google, I am attempting to Export Google's proprietary formats.I am able to download non-proprietary formats just fine.

To get the path for the file, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) says to call:

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.getExportLinks("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
```

to export (for example) a Google Document as a MS Word document. Doing this results in an apparently valid URL. (I've also tried this with "text/plain", with the same result).

However, when I attempt to download from that path, The Google Drive SDK throws a NullPointerException internally:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:194)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:150)
at com.redacted.mycode.GoogleDocsConnection.download(GoogleDocsConnection.java:182)
...
```

Is anybody else experiencing this? I'm considering modifying Google's SDK myself, but I wanted to see if anyone has already run into this problem (and maybe found a solution).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

I didn't read the initial question thoroughly and didn't notice that this happens only for documents in Google-native formats.

Once you have a valid export link for the document, you have to build an authorized GET request. The code to do that is similar to the one from the `files.get` snippet below, you just need to replace the download url with the export url:

```
private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, String exportUrl) {
  try {
    HttpResponse resp =
        service.getRequestFactory()
            .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(exportUrl))
            .execute();
    return resp.getContent();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // An error occurred.
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER (please ignore):**

The NullPointer exception might be caused by an unauthorized initial download request. The following code shows how to download a file from Drive:

```
private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
  if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
    try {
      HttpResponse resp =
          service.getRequestFactory()
              .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
              .execute();
      return resp.getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // An error occurred.
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return null;
  }
}
```

Just make sure the `service` instance you are passing to `downloadFile` is correctly authorized.

If you are using this code and you are sure your service is correctly authorized, please show the HTTP request sent by your app and the corresponding response.

Comment: getDownloadUrl() returns null for Google's proprietary formats. As I mentioned in my post, I am able to download non-proprietary files just fine, which is what this post will do. This post, however, will end up having `null` passed in if the file in question is, say, a Google Document

Comment: Well, despite the fact that this code directly contradicts the Documentation that Google has provided, your answer works. As a final request, would you please cite the source of this answer? If you do, I'll happily give you the accepted answer and the bounty and remove the downvote.

Comment: I wrote that code myself based on the previous code and knowing how the library builds an authorized request. Where is the contradiction with the documentation? I'm part of the Developer Relations team for Google Drive and I'll be happy to clarify our docs.

Comment: I apologize. I retract the statement that this is undocumented; I found it. Anyway, thank you very much for your help :)